# Prism How to bind Module View to app wide property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, binding, prism

I know this may seem silly but, what is the best way to bind to Application Wide properties using MVVM and Prism?

**Problem**: `ConnectionStatus Status {...}` (Implements INotifyPropertyChanged etc..)

How do I go about accessing this property in specific modules? I want to be able to use the Status property across different modules?

What is the best way of getting this data across different modules?

**Solutions**

Currently I am leaning towards having the following view model in the infrastructure project (shared across modules)

```
namespace Project.Infrastructure 
{
    public class AppViewModel
    {
        public ConnectionStatus Status {...}
    }
}
```

And in IoC define `AppViewModel` as `Singleton`, and pass this in the constructor of `ModuleViewModel`

```
namespace Project.ModuleA 
{
    AppViewModel _appViewModel;

    public class ModuleViewModel
    {
        public ModuleViewModele(AppViewModel appViewModel)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is this the best way to do this or is there a better way of doing this?

E.g.

1. Using `EventAggregator`  and `ConnectionStatusChangeEvent` to subscribe and publish to changes in the connection? But in this case if someone subscribes to the event after it got pubblished (such as online) they will not get any starting value, so a `IStatusService` could be used at the start?
2. Using `RegionContext` and binding that to the `Status` property in the `Shell`? But this seems to defeat the purpose of `Shell` not knowing what the Modules use etc..

Or is there something that I have completely missed?

I have read the whole Prism(v4) documentation and just not 100% sure of which is the best way of implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not like ViewModels knowing about each other. I took the approach you listed in E.g #1 - that EventAggregator assists in moving information around for me.  I do this currently with a database connection and settings, both used throughout viewmodels.  I pass the model property around after it is created first time and when updated.

The ViewModel that creates the model subscribes to a Request and UpdateRequest, and publishes a Response.  So a Request returns the current property, UpdateRequest will refresh or recreate as appropriate.

The Response is pushing to any listeners - such as a newly created ViewModel who has in its constructor a publish of the Request. This means that the constructor doesn't initialize everything, your going to have the Response listeners covering extra work, and sometimes you may need to wait for multiple responses to fully initialize.

---

You asked *what is the best way...* - I feel my answer is *right*, but do what is right for your project. I like strict MVVM, but it doesn't always have to be so rigid.